# CFPrint, barcodes and special characters

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, cfprint

I've created a PDF using `CFDOCUMENT`, using a barcode font in the stylesheet for certain elements.  When the resulting barcode contains a single quote (') or ampersand (&), that character is replaced with a blank space when printing with `CFPRINT`, but the PDF displays and prints fine from Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Printers affected Zebra TLP 2844, LabelTac 4 (Creative).  Drivers provided by Seagull Scientific.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: Can you show us your code? That may help us to find the issue.

Comment: We have isolated the issue to the specific printer driver we're using to print.  The printer is a LabelTac 4. Others experiencing similar issues will want to check for driver updates for their printers.
I'm working with their team to determine a resolution.

Comment: post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have isolated the issue to the specific printer driver we're using to print.  The printer is a LabelTac 4. Others experiencing similar issues will want to check for driver updates for their printers.
I'm working with their team to determine a resolution.

Updates to the latest driver from Seagull Scientific resulted in no change to the output.  Seagull Scientific does not provide support for their drivers without the purchase of their BarTender software.